# How do I let a native component decide its own size

Tags: android, react-native

I have a react native project, and I need to embed a third-party native control (which I don't have the source code to or any influence over).

I have defined my own wrapper component:

```java
public class MyWrapperView extends LinearLayout {
    private ThirdPartyView mThirdPartyView;

    public MyWrapperView(ThemedReactContext context) {
        super(context);
        mThirdPartyView = new ThirdPartyView();
        addView(mThirdPartyView);
    }
}
```

This works, and the view is visible, but my problem is that the size of the view is decided by the react-native layout algorithm. I.e, if I do

```js
function SomeComponent() {
  return (
    <View>
      <MyWrapperView />
    </View>
  );
}
```

my wrapper component will be invisible because it is given a height of 0.

I could add

```js
function SomeComponent() {
  return (
    <View>
      <MyWrapperView style={{height: 50}} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

which will make the component visible, but the problem is: I don't know which height to use. The height can also change dynamically depending on external communication in the component.

I have verified that `onMeasure` is invoked with `MeasureSpec.EXACTLY`, so React native clearly wants to decide how big my view should be.

How can I specify that I want my view to be as big as it wants, and then the container should adapt to it?

How can I

Comment: Hi @erikkallen, Did you find any workaround on this?

Comment: @BharathKumar Just added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around the problem with code like this:

```
public void initializeSizeChecker() {
    Choreographer.getInstance().postFrameCallback(new 
    Choreographer.FrameCallback() {
        @Override
        public void doFrame(long frameTimeNanos) {
            View childView = getTheChildView();
            int width = childView.getWidth();
            int height = childView.getHeight();

            if (width != getWidth() || height != getHeight()) {
                measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width,  View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));

                int left = getLeft();
                int top = getTop();
                layout(left, top, left + width, top + height);

                onSizeChange((int)PixelUtil.toDIPFromPixel(width), (int)PixelUtil.toDIPFromPixel(height));

                getViewTreeObserver().dispatchOnGlobalLayout();
            }

            Choreographer.getInstance().postFrameCallback(this);
        }
    });
}

private void onSizeChange(int width, int height) {
    WritableMap event = Arguments.createMap();
    event.putInt("width", width);
    event.putInt("height", height);
    ReactContext reactContext = (ReactContext)getContext();
    reactContext
            .getJSModule(RCTEventEmitter.class)
            .receiveEvent(getId(), "sizeChange", event);
}
```

and then in my JS:

```
function ComponentWrapper() => {
  const [height, setHeight] = React.useState(0);

  const onSizeChange = React.useCallback(e => {
    setHeight(e.nativeEvent.height);
  }, []);

  return <NativeComponent style={{ height }} onSizeChange={onSizeChange} />;
}
```